# Linear Combinations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am currently trying to learn linear combinations and am stuck on two different problems.

The first states:

```
Im given x1 = (4,3) x2 = (1,1) and x3 = (5,4). Find two linear combinations that get z = (1,0).
```

So does this mean adding and subtracting these together to find ways of get (1,0). If so, I can not find any way to do this because I keep getting (1,1) or (0,0). Am I having the correct approach?

The second problem of this kind is:

x1 = $\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\\4\end{bmatrix}$ x2 = $\begin{bmatrix}3\\1\\6\end{bmatrix}$ x3 = $\begin{bmatrix}7\\-3\\10\end{bmatrix}$

It says find a linear combination of the vectors that give the zero vector? Would I do the say as above and try to get it to all zeros?

Thanks a lot

Comment: A linear combination of n elements $\lbrace v_1,v_2,...,v_n\rbrace$ is of the form $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_iv_i$ where $a_j$ is a scalar for $j=1,...,n$.

What you're forgetting is the scalars.

Comment: For your first example, recall that the set of linear combinations of $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$ is probably $\{ax_1 + bx_2 + cx_3 : a,b,c \in \mathbb{R} \}$, where I say "probably" because it depends on what your coefficients are allowed to be (changing the "$ a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$" part). I imagine you're allowed to use all real numbers, in which case $\pi x_1 - \sqrt{2}x_2 + (1/5)x_3$ is a valid linear combination. Does that help you find more combinations?

Answer (score 3):

We need to find two solutions to $$a(4,3)+b(1,1)+c(5,4)=(1,0)$$ for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ (I presume).  This is equivalent to finding two solutions to the system of equations
\begin{align*}
4a+b+5c &= 1 \\
3a+b+4c &= 0.
\end{align*}
If there's one solution, there will be infinitely many (since there will be a free variable).

For this problem in particular, there's a way to "cheat": (a) try $a=0$ and find values of $b$ and $c$ that work by inspection, and (b) try $c=0$ and find values of $a$ and $b$ that work by inspection.

The second question is similar, we want to find $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ (not all zero) such that
$$a\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\\4\end{bmatrix} +b \begin{bmatrix}3\\1\\6\end{bmatrix}+c  \begin{bmatrix}7\\-3\\10\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\\end{bmatrix}$$

This time, it's probably easier to solve the system of equations
\begin{align*}
a+3b+7c &=0 \\
3a+b-3c &=0 \\
4a+6b+10c &=0.
\end{align*}
using [Gaussian elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So following your steps I would get a = 0, b = -4 and c = 1 & a = 1, b = -3 and c = 0. So I found my answer once I get that?

Comment: Exactly, but I would write them out explicitly: $0(4,3)-4(1,1)+1(5,4)=(1,0)$ and $1(4,3)-3(1,1)+0(5,4)=(1,0)$ to demonstrate that you understand what the coefficients mean.

Comment: Thank you! For the second, wont everyone be zero because its the zero vector?

Comment: I did elimination and got -6c = 0 but wont they all get to zero?

Comment: @user081608 if the three vectors are linearly *independent*, then yes, $a,b,c$ all *have* to go to zero to add up to the zero vector.  If they're linearly *dependent* then you can find $a,b,c$ not all zero that give the zero vector.

Comment: Ah yes, I'll add "not all zero" to my answer.  [Although, technically, the question asks for a linear combination, and the all-zero combination is a linear combination.]

Comment: Okay that makes sense but I am unsure of how to not get all zeros?

Comment: @user081608 Do you know row-reduction/gaussian elimination? Using that method, you reduce the matrix in either upper/lower triangular form and then the solutions of the $0$ vector without $a$, $b$ and $c$ being $0$ will present themselves.

Comment: @Zhoe Yes I ended up getting \begin{align*} a+3b+7c &= 0 \\
-5b-24c &= 0\\-6c &= 0 .
\end{align*} And this will give C = 0 which will make everything else zero. Am I wrong?

Comment: I calculated the determinant and got that it is $0$ (this means the vectors are linearly dependent). So check your row-reduction (I also used a row-reducing calculator and got that the last row is a row entirely of $0$'s). Should get $$\begin{pmatrix}1&3&7\\0&1&3\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$.

Comment: So I would do b = -3c and plug that in?

Comment: @user081608 From this you would get the pair of equations $$b+3c=0\\a+3b+7c=0$$ 

$b=-3c\space, a=-3b-7c\space$ where $c$ can be any variable of your choice.

So putting $c=2$ for example, $b=-6$ and $a=4$ and this holds (you can test for yourself):

$$4\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\\4\end{bmatrix} -6 \begin{bmatrix}3\\1\\6\end{bmatrix}+2  \begin{bmatrix}7\\-3\\10\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\\end{bmatrix}$$ You can sub. $b=-3c$ in the second equation to make $a$ simpler.

Answer (score 3):

A linear combination means adding scalar multiples of the two vectors.

If your (real) vectors have dimension $2$ then if you have two vectors (a) neither of which is the zero vector, and (b) one is not a scalar multiple of the other, then you can create a linear combination of them to get any other two-dimensional (real) vectors.

So, for example, $\vec{x_1} - 3 \vec{x_2} = \vec{z}.$  Here, $z$ is a linear combination of $x_1, x_2.$

A more general way of solving this is to look at each component individually as its own equation.  So we're looking for scalars $a,b$ such that:

$$a \cdot \vec{x_1} + b \cdot \vec{x_2} = \vec{z}.$$

This implies

$$a \cdot 4 + b \cdot 1 = 1 \\ a \cdot 3 + b \cdot 1 = 0$$

or

$$4a + b = 1 \\ 3a + b = 0$$

Subtracting the second equation from the first gives $a=1$ and then resubstituting gives $b=-3$ which is what we found above.

Doing this for three-dimensional vectors works exactly the same way, except you'll have three equations.